# Scala covariant doc example allows apples and oranges

Tags: scala, covariance

See this implementation follows the upper bound example http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/upper-type-bounds.html

```
class Fruit(name: String) 
 class Apple (name: String) extends Fruit(name)
 class Orange(name: String) extends Fruit(name)
 class BigOrange(name:String) extends Orange(name)
 class BigFLOrange(name:String) extends BigOrange(name)

// Straight from the doc
trait Node[+B ] {
  def prepend[U >: B ](elem: U)
}

case class ListNode[+B](h: B, t: Node[B]) extends Node[B] {
  def prepend[U >:B  ](elem: U) = ListNode[U](elem, this)
  def head: B = h
  def tail = t
}

case class Nil[+B ]() extends Node[B] {
  def prepend[U >: B ](elem: U) = ListNode[U](elem, this)
}
```

But this definition seems to allow multiple unrelated things in the same container

```
      val f = new Fruit("fruit")
      val a = new Apple("apple")
      val o = new Orange("orange")
      val bo = new BigOrange("big orange")  

      val foo :ListNode[BigOrange] = ListNode[BigOrange](bo, Nil())
      foo.prepend(a) // add an apple to BigOrangeList
      foo.prepend(o) // add an orange to BigOrangeList

      val foo2 : ListNode[Orange] = foo  // and still get to assign to OrangeList
```

So I am not sure this is a great example in the docs. And, question, how doe I modify the constraints so that..this behaves more like a List?

User @gábor-bakos points out that I am confusing invariance with covariance. So I tried the  mutable list buffer. It does not later allow apple to be inserted into an Orange list Buffer, but it is not covariant

```
val ll : ListBuffer[BigOrange]= ListBuffer(bo)
  ll += bo //good
  ll += a // not allowed
```

So..can my example above (ListNode) be modified so that
 1. it is covariant (it already is)
 2 It is mutable, but mutable like the ListBuffer example (will not later allow apples to be inserted into BigOrange list

Comment: I am not sure what you mean/ask. Do you want a covariant list to behave like an invariant list?

Comment: hmm, ok. So  covariance and invariance are 2 separate concepts. How can I make this example invariant? Specifically, how do I add a constructor that infers the type i.e. so that the compiler will mark the following as invalid:

Comment: to make it invariant, remove the `+`  sign before `B`. Also, loose the type parameter in `prepend`, and make the parameter type `B`.

Answer (score 1):

A mutable list cannot/should not be covariant in its argument type. 
Exactly because of the reason you noted.

Suppose, you could have a `MutableList[Orange]`, that was a subclass of a `MutableList[Fruit]`. Now, there is nothing that would prevent you from making a function:

```
 def putApple(fruits: MutableList[Fruit], idx: Int) = 
     fruits(idx) = new Apple
```

You can add `Apple` to the list of `Fruits`, because `Apple` is a `Fruit`, nothing wrong with this.
But once you have a function like that, there is no reason you can't call it like this:

```
 val oranges = new MutableList[Orange](new Orange, new Orange)
 putApple(oranges, 0)
```

This will compile, since `MutableList[Orange]` is a subclass of `MutableList[Fruit]`. But now:

```
val firstOrange: Orange = oranges(0)
```

will crash, because the first element of `oranges` is actually an `Apple`.

For this reason, mutable collections have to be invariant in the element type (to answer the question you asked in the comments, to make the list invariant remove the `+` before `B`, and also get rid of the type parameter in `prepend`. It should just be `def pretend(elem: B)`).

How to get around it? The best solution is to simply not use mutable collections. You should not need them in 99% or real life scala code. If you think you need one, there is a 99% you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The major thing that you are probably missing is that `prepend` does not modify a list. In the line `val foo2 : ListNode[Orange] = foo` the list `foo` is still of type `ListNode[BigOrange]` and given covariance of parameters this assignment is valid (and there is nothing particularly awkward about it). Compiler will prevent you from assigning `Fruits` to `Oranges` (in this case assigning an `Apple` to an `Orange` is hazardous) but you have to save modified lists beforehand:

```
val foo: ListNode[Fruit] = ListNode[BigOrange](bo, Nil()).prepend(a).prepend(o)
val foo2: ListNode[Orange] = foo  // this is not valid
```

Moreover your `Node` definition lacks return type for `prepend` - thus compiler infers wrong return type (`Unit` instead of `ListNode[U]`).

Here's fixed version:

```
trait Node[+B] {
  def prepend[U >: B ](elem: U): Node[U]
}
```

Comment: The return type should actually be `Node[U]` (ListNode is not yet defined at this point).

Comment: It can be `ListNode[U]`, it only wouldn't work if you are entering the definitions in REPL one-by-one.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov it can be but it's also more coherent when we are using Node in Node context

Comment: now you can do things like `node.prepend(120)` or `node.prepend("foo")` this will all compile